# OData dynamic template class

Tags: c#, odata

I am working with OData V3, and i came across this line:

```
var people = await client.For<People>().FindEntriesAsync();
```

In order for this to work, I need to define the `People` class, which has a bunch of set/get, which represent the fields I want.

Is there a simple and convenient way to avoid hard coding the structure classes? I want to be able to issue that command without having to define a specific "People" class. I would much rather have my results be in dictionary form, were the key's would be the column name, and the value would be the value in that column for the specific object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.OData.Client supports untyped scenarios, in which the CLR class is unnecessary.

For example:

```
var people = await client.For("People").FindEntriesAsync();
```

Then, `people` is a dictionary instance that you can use `IDictionary<string, object>` to refer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to avoid define a class like People, but if you really want to do this, you can try [un-typed feature](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-10-open-type-in-untyped-scenarios) in OData.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.OData.Client supports typed, untyped and dynamic scenario. So you can rewrite your query like this:

```
var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
var people = await client.For(x.People).FindEntriesAsync();
```

here is another example:

```
var person = await client
    .For(x.People)
    .Filter(x.FirstName == "John")
    .Select(x.LastName)
    .FindEntryAsync();
```